# ExpandoObject Property not found

Tags: c#, .net, expandoobject

Here is a ViewModel property definition.

```
private List<ExpandoObject> productList;

public List<ExpandoObject> Products {
    get {

        return productList;
    }

    set {

        productList = value;

    }
}
```

On the selectedProduct ExpandoObject, I have a property named lineNum, which is set in the standard way for ExpandoObjects:

```
product.lineNum = some_integer;
```

Now, inside a method residing within another object, I have this.  object_passed_in is declared as Object, and a member of the productList is passed into it.

```
var selectedProduct = object_passed_in as ExpandoObject 
// I have tried this as "dynamic", too
```

When I set a breakpoint and watch "selectedProduct.lineNum" the watch works just fine - it shows the correct value.  However...

```
if (selectedProduct.lineNum == some_comparison_value) {

    // some lines of code
}
```

throws an error - a first chance exception, telling me that lineNum is not a property found on ExpandoObject selectedProduct.

I can beat the ExpandoObject into submission by casting it to an IDictionary< string,object > type, and then accessing the property this way:

```
int passed_in_lineNum = (int)selectedProduct["lineNum"];
```

but that totally defeats the purpose of using an ExpandoObject!

What.  Am.  I.  Doing.  Wrong.  Here???

Comment: May i ask why are you using such a construct? Using an ExpandoObject seems like a pretty nasty code smell, and an architectural one as well (Obviously, this does not apply when you are interfacing with DLR languages).

Comment: Fair question - I'm working with a bunch of properties which are loaded into the program from an external source - dynamically -  They can be whatever the user wants them to be, so we don't know what they are named at compile-time.  We know neither the number of, nor the names of them, so ExpandoObject seems to be the right fit for this application.

Comment: @Machinarius - would you take a different approach?  If so, I'm curious...

Comment: I'd go with an old-fashioned Key-Value store that i can persist. Redis maybe? Assuming the user-defined keys can be hashed and their values are mere strings (Or can be encoded as such), a KVP hashmap will be faster and the intent will be clearer, as that is their sole purpose.

Comment: I'll have to look into that; for sure.  I don't know if it applies in this particular case, I'd need to do some more digging before coming to a decision.  This question is based on only a very small snippet of the larger application, though, most of which I deliberately left out.  The various other aspects of this project do, however, make the issue more complex than that.  That said, thanks for the pointer - I'll definitely be following it up.

Comment: No problem. A Dictionary will be faster than reflection on a DLR object, i think. Might be worth a performance test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have "Enable Just My Code" unchecked under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General? Since, this is a first chance exception, it's highly possible that the DLR throws and catches it (I was able to reproduce this with "Enable Just My Code" unchecked). Try ignoring the exception or checking "Enable Just My Code" and see if it works.

Comment: ... aaaaaand that seems to have fixed it; after, of course, I've totally changed every reference to the ExpandoObject in the code.

grrrr :)